# how to share a folder between two projects in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If I have a project called '`testing`' in project A.

How can I share that folder '`testing`' for project B in visual studio 2010?

The reason I would like to achieve about this is because when I change something in the folder testing of project A, I dont want to change the same things in project B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2006/11/29/quick-tip-sharing-code-between-multiple-projects-in-visual-studio-2005.aspx but it is for a file. I would like to share a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share folders in Visual Studio - they are logical constructs that are part of a solution or project.

The closest you can get is to add folders to the projects you need to share on and add all the files that you want to share as links. You will still need to manually synchronize all adds/deletes of files, but updates will come across all projects.

To make things easier, you may want to write a [Visual Studio macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that synchronizes these folders for you (you can bind these to keyboard shortcuts and/or menu items).

Comment: if I download the source code from this project: http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/ I see that there are different projects in a solution sharing same folders.

Comment: @devn - Are you certain that deleting/adding an item is something that replicates across projects?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late for the person who asked the question, but this is for people with similar problems.  You can share folder contents with an extention  'Project Linker':

This builds upon the concept of linked files where you refer to the same file from two projects. This extention handles the management of that for an entire project. If you add a file to the project, it will be added too to the other project as a linked file. Same for deletes...

Attention: you need to have both projects in the same solution for this to work of coarse...

[Extention VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108(v=pandp.20).aspx)

I used it in VS2010 and it's also availible for later versions.

Answer (score -1):

If you put your solution (*.sln) files in the same directory they can share files in sub directories.